# How do I take a screengrab of a single window using Cocoa or Carbon on OS X?

Tags: cocoa, macos, screenshot, macos-carbon

I need to be able to identify a single window on the user's screen and take a screen capture of it.  The screen data is to be stored in memory and not written to disk.

This is already supported through the commandline tool /usr/sbin/screencapture or through the Grab utility (though their functionality is not extensive enough to justify me launching them as a subprocess).

**References / Hints**

- nm /usr/sbin/screencapture returns private Cocoa interfaces including _CGSGetSharedWindow that appear to do this.
- Third party application Snapzpro does this (but does not provide source code)

Comment: i would advise against using Carbon - its pretty much on its way to being completely deprecated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mac OS X 10.5 introduced the [Quartz Window Services API](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html) to do just this.

Comment: This does the trick.  A short Google provided sample code, rigged with profiling. http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/SonOfGrab/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to mind was GrabFS from MacFuse. The source is [here](http://macfuse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/filesystems/grabfs/).

Answer (score -4):

Command+Shift+4 to activate the screenshot selection, then tap the space bar to select the whole window.